# How to print the address of char array

Tags: c++, c++11

http://ideone.com/4p1gqr

```
#include <iostream>    

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  float *f = new float[10];

  std::cout << f << std::endl;
  std::cout << f + 3 << std::endl;

  char *c = new char[10];
  std::cout << c << std::endl;       // no print
  std::cout << c + 3 << std::endl;   // no print

  return 0;
}

stdout 
0x2b3cbaf1bc20
0x2b3cbaf1bc2c
```

How to print the address of char array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to cast to `void*` to invoke correct overload of `operator <<` instead of outputting as C strings

```
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(c) << std::endl;
std::cout << static_cast<void*>(c+3) << std::endl;
```